# Ask your crush out

Tags: word-usage, phrases, expressions, idioms, nouns

I found that when you want to ask whether he or she can go dating with you, you say " ask him or her out"

And also I found when you have a crush on someone and that is one-sided love, you call the one "crush"

So is it okay to say "ask your crush out" ?

I'm not sure and I have a strange feeling about this because it's made only of terms I don't know.

Thanks.

P.s.
Maybe I'm not good at making English sentence so if there're any things that make you feel " a bit weird" , I'd be very glad to be noticed.

Comment: Yes, that sentence makes sense to a native English speaker. To make what you're saying even more clear, you could say that you "ask your crush out *on a date.*"

Comment: I just want to point out that if someone is your crush, it doesn't necessarily mean that it is one-sided. They could also like you back and you could be fully aware of it and still call them your crush.

Comment: @Phil14 Indeed, though I think this is being contrasted with things like girlfriend/boyfriend, partner, etc. where the word requires that it be reciprocal. Usually you talk about your crush as the person you'd *like* to be in a mutual relationship with, and once you're in that relationship they get upgraded to girlfriend/boyfriend, partner, or whatever. :) I think you'd only keep calling them your crush if you both liked each other but for whatever reason didn't enter any such relationship.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence that you have written can be said in a number of ways.

1. Ask your crush out.
2. Ask your crush *out on a date.*
3. Ask out your crush. (More informal)
4. Ask your crush to go out with you.

As you can see, the sentence you wrote was completely correct, and there was nothing weird about it.

Also, as Phil14 said in a comment above, a crush *need not be a one-sided relationship*, unless you already know it.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: But again, although your crush may feel the same way about you (i.e. it is not *unrequited* love), note that once you are in a relationship with someone, they are no longer called your "crush".